# post form in django, get blank screen, broken or bug?

Tags: python, django, mobile

I've created a form in django which works fine on desktop browsers, but on mobile browsers when the form submits it just displays a blank screen (doesn't even load the title or an error), am I missing something?

If there's no way to make it work using post, how could I submit a form to `locations/<zip  code>` or use get `locations/?zip_code=<zip code>`? (I'm a django noob, sorry)

here's the relevant code:

template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

form.py:

```
class ZipForm(forms.Form):
    zip_code = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
```

views.py:

```
def zip(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ZipForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            zip_code = form.cleaned_data['zip_code']
            ## get result    
            return render_to_response("zip.html",{
                'title':'Closest Locations',
                'results' : results,
                'form' : form,
            })
    else:
        form = ZipForm()
    return render_to_response("zip.html", {
        'form' : form,
        'title' : 'Find Locations',
    })
```

url.py:

```
url(r'^locations/$', 'app.views.zip'),
```

I wish there was a decent debugger for developing on mobile phones, ugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the form is valid then you do all this fancy stuff... but you forgot to handle the case where the form *isn't* valid.

Comment: duh, thanks! documentation just kinda skims over that, or at least doing it in the view https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view

Comment: actually this was giving me a 403 silently (even though debug was on) but you're statement is also true.  I had to add `@csrf_exempt` to the views.py to decorate `zip(request)`